# Material button causes render error (IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-button

Whenever I add a material button to my layout, it shows render error. It shows IllegalArgumentExcpetion. I have been using these dependencies,

```xml
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

And my styles.xml is,

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My layout file is,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/material_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Error stack is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@6eda1529
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor356.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:674)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:637)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1069)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1088)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.startWithoutPulsing(ValueAnimator.java:1081)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.handleAnimationEvents(AnimatorSet.java:1142)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.startAnimation(AnimatorSet.java:1227)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:729)
    at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:684)
    at android.animation.StateListAnimator.start(StateListAnimator.java:188)
    at android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:181)
    at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:21105)
    at android.widget.TextView.drawableStateChanged(TextView.java:5283)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.drawableStateChanged(AppCompatButton.java:155)
    at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:21160)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18379)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:335)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:391)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:540)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:666)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have been trying all the answers from stackoverflow but they seem to lead me nowhere. I tried to use other material compenents like material cardview and they were working fine. Please help.

Comment: Add the error stacktrace also .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was confirmed to be a bug with MDC v1.1.0-alpha07. To fix it, just downgrade MDC to v1.0.0 and restart android studio. (clean and rebuild doesn't seem to work).